Can I create a custom annotation to supress the lint warning about my public API properties or functions in Kotlin?
Android studio always give me warnings about unused public properties or functions.
It suggests me that the function is never used and property could be private.
But they are APIs. How can I supress the warnings on the specific APis? Is there a annotation named 'Api' to supress them? Or can I create a custom one?
My unit test can not cover them.

I am not answering your question directly, but out of the box detekt does what you want: https://detekt.dev/
